# 404 and 403 Errors after site migration

Tags: .htaccess

I have migrated a site from one server to another and the page just refuses to work.

I have all modules enabled as on the old server, .htaccess is present in the root folder yet when i access the site through URL i get

```
The requested page could not be found.
```

when i add 'q' param like so: `/?q=user`

I get the user login screen however when i try to log in i get access denied.

apache error logs are clear. The configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        <Directory "/var/www/site/">
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>      
</VirtualHost>
```

running Apache2.4

.htaccess

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
#ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php
#DirectoryIndex phpinfo.php
# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Tried to access admin sections for clear urls but i get access denied - i just can not access any page really. Not sure if there is anything i can do via DB.

**EDIT:**

This is very interesting find - it turned out that the database encoding was wrong.. So i had to drop the cluster and recreate it with correct encoding (and that meant changing machine locale).  The DB encoding was LATIN but its supposed to be UTF-8. After doing so everything works as expected.

Comment: have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/5590

Comment: @undersound the URL changed but i still get `Page Not Found` on every single page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because clean urls are enabled. After you logged in at ?q=user/login go to ?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls and check if you have clean urls working (you should see a checkbox appear). Otherwise check the following.

- check if rewrite_module is enabled
- check if .htacces files exists in root dir
- check contents of .htacess for rewriting
- check permission of .htaccess
- check if AllowOverride is set to all. AllowOverride all

Comment: So the `clean-urls` checkbox is set to Dissable (when clicked on Enable and save it reverts back to Dissable even though it says configuration save). .htaccess is present and there is rewrite content - read question. Permissions are 755 on .htaccess(overkill but sufficient). allow override set to all again read the question

Comment: do you have it overridden in your settings.php file somewhere by setting `$conf['clean_url'] = 0;`?

Comment: perhaps also check this page https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls

Comment: It seems like i had this enabled in settings.php probably from my earlier trials. That now removed, and clean url enabled i still get page not found on every single page -including the main page

Comment: what happens when you disable clean urls (let it stay disabled) and clear all your caches?

Comment: still page not found. and it drives me nuts...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56492/discussion-between-undersound-and-maciej-cygan).